# Google Charts Line Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm new to google charts and can't seem to figure out how i would do something of the following:

I want to make a data table that has my xcord,ycord,legendlabel. I'm trying the following:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);   

            data.addColumn("number","reps");
            data.addColumn("number","weight");
            data.addColumn("string","legendlabel")

            data.addColumn("string","workoutname");

            data.addRows([[150, 10,"workoutA"],
                          [300, 2,"workoutB"], //format [xcord,ycord,legendlabel] 

                        ]);
```

However, it isn't working obviously because we have two different types, number and string.

Is there a way i can specify the xcord, ycord then have a label for this point, then if there are multiple labels that are the same it forms a line graph?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

With a line chart each data line has to have a value for every point on the domain or else the line will be broken, What you want is a [scatter chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart)

Then data for you graph should look something like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);   

data.addColumn("number","reps");
data.addColumn("number","workout1");
data.addColumn("number","workout2");

data.addRows([
    [150, 10, null],
    [300, null, 2,]
]);
```

you will want to set the **lineWidth** to see the trending curve

```
chart.draw(data, {
    lineWidth: 2,
    vAxis: {title: "reps"},
    hAxis: {title: "weight"}
}
```